# How to install php without Apache webserver?

Tags: php

It seems that the only way to do this is to install together an Apache server which is very-very unwanted (in our case).

We just want to utilize the simple [built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), as the lucky users of some non-ubuntu OSes (like MS Windows 10) have.

Comment: What is the purpose? Installing PHP without Apache or installing PHP with something other than Apache?

Comment: How comes you think that you can install php only together with Apache. Just `sudo apt install php` will do.

Comment: @Yaron  Sorry for not understanding the comment, we just want the same benefit windows users have.

Comment: @pLumo No. It installs Apache also.

Comment: @iliasiliadis Windows and Ubuntu are **different entities** and operate differently.  When you install PHP in Windows, it also configures IIS Web Server to deploy the PHP typically.  Are you intending to use straight PHP without any web server, or PHP as a web backend?

Comment: @Thomas Ward ...If there is an IIS Web Server. The link to php.net I gave, says nothing about an extra web server required to run on the machine.

Comment: @iliasiliadis this doesn't answer my question which is "Are you intending to use PHP without a web server or use PHP as a web backend?"  This question will determine the ***PROPER*** answer. as to what you have to default install.  For example, `php-cli` will give you the `php` command on command line to run PHP scripts, but `php-fpm` or `libapache2-mod-php7.2` (the most commonly installed PHP package in Ubuntu for Apache PHP support, hence why just doing `apt install php` installs Apache and that package) will give you a PHP web backend system.  We need more details to properly answer you.

Comment: As the question already says: We just want to utilize the simple built-in web server. Sorry, but cannot make that more clear.

Comment: @iliasiliadis, what about my answer ?!

Comment: There **is** no inbulit webserver to PHP, unless you've written a lib/wrapper around it.  For that, you'd need `php-cli` and then launch PHP via a similar command like in the answer below.  By default, though, PHP **has** no Web Server set up for it - this is why you need Apache or nginx+php-fpm to get to a web backend for PHP.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ubuntu [package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2) says `php` (`php7.2`) depends on `libapache2-mod-php7.2` **OR** `php7.2-fpm` **OR** `php7.2-cgi`.

It seems to default to the first package, which itself depends on `apache2`. But if you install one of the latter first, and `php` afterwards, `apache2` will not be installed.

```
sudo apt install php-cgi
sudo apt install php
```

or manually put the resolved dependency:

```
sudo apt install php php7.2-cgi
```

Then you can run

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: Tried this. Seems that cgi is not enough (still installs apache). So I tried both php-fpm and php-cgi which appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

For the benefit of anyone still looking up this question:
To install PHP without Apache (either to use on its own or with nginx) you have to install FPM directly rather than installing just "php". So just use this:

```
apt install php-fpm php-cli
```

(Yes, it's obnoxious that the "php" package assumes Apache.)

And be careful installing some of the PHP module packages; they sometimes try to install Apache as well. (Astonishing that after all these years Ubuntu's PHP packages still try to force the use of Apache `mod-php` instead of using `php-fpm`!)

If Apache *does* get installed against your will, you can purge it with the following (yes, oddly, you have to purge both of these packages):

```
apt purge apache2 apache2-bin
```

Also, after installing PHP, always be sure to set the `date.timezone` option in both `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` (adjust according to the version you've installed).

Comment: “Yes, it's obnoxious that the "php" package assumes Apache.” Yes it is – but then again, Apache was THE one and only webserver for PHP scripts for more than 20 years now! Let's call it “for historic reasons”…

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends --dry-run install php
```

First simulate. I'm not in ubuntu now. If you are happy you can run

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install php
```

Comment: This won't work as installing `php` will install a web server to go with it as it defaults to the Apache module first.  OP would have to install either the `php-cgi` package or `php-cli` package *first* before trying to install `php` - however if they install php-cgi or php-cli they'll get all the PHP common dependencies anyways which does not include a web server.

Comment: you a right in bionic is it this way. I was in xenial.